# I need to print array values in angular js using ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an array values like **[0,1,5,10]**. 
I need the output to be like this 
**0
1
b
b
b
5
b
b
b
b
10**

For the empty values inside the array, I want to print as **b**. How can i do it with the ng-repeat and I dont want the static coding it want it to be dynamic.

my code is like this :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) { 
        $scope.q = [0,1,5,10];
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="i in q">{{i}}</div>
</div>
```

And one more thing id don't want to create a new array using array.push() method.
Please help me on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: You must create a new array, because you don't have empty values in your array, you just have missing numbers, so need to create a new array with missing values markers.

Comment: **And one more thing i don't want to create a new array using array push. Please help me on this and thanks in advance.**

Comment: We don't have any options using like for loop in angular js ??

Comment: OK How to create an array using push?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) { 
        $scope.q = [0,1,5,10];
        $scope.temp = function(){
          var answer = [];
          for(var i =  $scope.q[0]; i <= $scope.q[$scope.q.length-1]; i++)
              answer.push($scope.q.indexOf(i) == -1 ? 'b' : i);
          return answer;
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="i in temp() track by $index">{{i}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.q = [0, 1, 5, 10];
  $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    if (num > 0) return new Array(num);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="i in q">
    <div ng-repeat="j in getNumber(q[$index] - q[$index-1]-1) track by $index">b</div>
    {{i}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At this case, html structure will be differ: div with "b" inside div, instead of single div

Comment: yeah..i guess..there was no requirement that we should not modify html..

Comment: i just tried to avoid 'pushing into array' as he said ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) { 
        $scope.q = [0,1,5,10];
  $scope.empties = function(index) {
   return index === 0 ? [] : new Array($scope.q[index] - $scope.q[index - 1] - 1);     
  }    
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>    
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">   
 <div ng-repeat = "i in q">
  <div ng-repeat = "empty in empties($index) track by $index">b</div>
  <div>{{i}}</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```